# The fixed 21s durations of spark streaming batch under Spark 2.1, no under Spark 2.0

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

**What's causing the fixed 21s duration of streaming batch under Spark 2.1?**

Under **Spark 2.1**, The streaming batches with small number of blocks (396),  their durations are all longer than 21s ... only a few less than 21s.

Kafka version : 0.10.0.0, Spark version : 2.1.0
spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.11-2.1.0.jar

a) And it's the same awful status under dev env with Spark 2.1.0, with much less streaming data, queued huge amount of active batches with 0 records.

[image: All durations are 21s, even with 0 records]

[image: Lots of active batches with 0 records]

b) The same task works fine under Spark 2.0.2 with **all the same depended jars**, and under Spark 2.1.0 - there's the 21s+ durations - it should not always take such a long duration.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Which task is the one causing the batched to be queued? You probably have an error in one of those tasks which are causing this halt.

Comment: everything works fine under spark 2.0.2. No specified error found under spark 2.1

Comment: I experienced the same kind of issue with spark 2.1.0 and not with 2.0.2. After few hours my job lag and some partition take 21s to complete insted of 2/3s. I think a regression with spark and kafka consumer has been introduced that cause timeout on consumed partition.

Comment: No more active batches lining up any more, under spark 2.2 snapshot

Comment: with spark 2.2 snapshot, the fixed duration will be 7s